# Can anyone find Putins Il-96-300PU july 17 flight map?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-planning, radar, online-tracking, flightradar24

Can anyone find Putin's Il-96-300PU July 17 flight track?

Putin's flight path has not been publicized on the internet. The Russian media is claiming that his aircraft would be in danger of being shot down, but has not shown that he would be even over Ukraine.  Initial information indicated that he was flying through Poland.

Is there a flight track for Vladimir Putin's aircraft on July 17?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I'm not sure if it belongs here.

Comment: it doesn't. Maybe on politics.se or conspiracytheories.se (if that existed, it would make a great place to move about half the topics of several other se sites).

Comment: Its what Russian media is telling since July 17. So its their official Politics. But never showing flight path on RossijaTV or RT or any media news.